# Unusual sequence of fractions

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Let's have the following sequence of fractions: $\frac{156}{51}, \frac{756}{251}, \frac{3756}{1251}, ? $ .

What fraction replaces the question mark?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next fraction is

> $$\frac{18756}{6251}$$

because

> the $n$-th fraction is given by
>  $$\frac{30\cdot 5^n+6}{10\cdot 5^n+1}.$$

In other words,

> to get the next fraction, keep the last digit of the numerator and denominator, and multiply the number formed by the remaining digits by 5.